# Posting data through AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Could anyone please explain to me how below code works, I want to know the significance of each field and what the possible values for each of them are.

Also please explain how it works as a whole. Thanks in advance

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "Controller/View",
 data: data,
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 dataType: "json"
});
```

Comment: I think the documentation here explains it well - https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: This is potentially the worst RTFM situation I have ever encountered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code pass and object to the $.ajax() function, the function reads the object and do the following:

**type** - Sets the HTTP request method, in your case to POST.

**url** - Modify the URL part of the request

**data** - Fill the body of the request and sets the Content-Length header accordinly

**contentType** - Sets the Content-Type header in the HTTP request which describe what type of content the request's body contains.

**dataType** - Sets the Accept header of the HTTP request which describe what type of data you expect to find in the body of the response from the server.

In the end your HTTP request might look something like this:

```
POST Controller/View HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Aceept: application/json
Content-Length: {length of data goes here}
{data itself goes here}
```

For further info about this function you can take a look in the JQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/